# Removing the text background of a label in a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

noticed my cell label got a background around its text, also some cell got bigger text then others (probably because of the background). Is there a way to remove this kind of behaviour ?

[image]

Comment: Stating the obvious: [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]], unless of course it is something more strange than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
[cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Click on the label Go to Attributes inspector and select colour as "Clear Colour" . this is the other way of doing it... and if u want to do it by code u have answers given by Nick and Kisel

Answer (score 1):

If it is UITableViewCell default label then obviously , as others answered

```
[cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

If you are using some custom cell with custom label in it,then in your UITableViewSubclass you will have to set

```
 label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

set the background color of that component to `[UIColor clearColor]`, but make sure to do that in `cellForRow:AtIndexPath` delegate method.